# Using GMAIL API with Symfony4

Tags: php, symfony, oauth, gmail

I am trying to use **Gmail API** with my symfony4 website. The goal is to execute a command regularly through a cron, that will fetch all unread email, get the content, and process some things, then mark them read.

I currently have (whet though [the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/php)):

- Installed the library through composer
- One new gmail account created for this, enabled the gmail API, and downloaded my "credentials.json"
- The working command from symfony (app:upload-from-unread-emails), with this code:

  ```
  $client = new \Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName('Gmail API PHP Quickstart');
  $client->addScope(\Google_Service_Gmail::GMAIL_READONLY);
  $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
  $client->setAccessType('offline');
  $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

  $gmail = new \Google_Service_Gmail($client);
  $list = $gmail->users_messages->listUsersMessages('me', ['maxResults' => 1000]);

  while ($list->getMessages() != null) {
      foreach ($list->getMessages() as $mlist) {

          $message_id = $mlist->id;
          var_dump($message_id);

      }

      if ($list->getNextPageToken() != null) {
          $pageToken = $list->getNextPageToken();
          $list = $gmail->users_messages->listUsersMessages('me', ['pageToken' => $pageToken, 'maxResults' => 1000]);
      } else {
          break;
      }
  }
  ```

Am I on the right track to authenticate ? Where am I supposed to drop my **credential.json** in symfony ?

Answer (score 3):

> Where am I supposed to drop my credential.json in symfony?

I think that the best place for this file will be the `config` folder. But you can set any path (except perhaps not in `public` =)).

Let's say the path for this file be `config/gmail/credentials.json`. So next step is get file path in command. For this you need get `kernel.project_dir` parameter from service container and concatenate `kernel.project_dir` and `/config/gmail/credentials.json`

For use service container in command you need:

- implement `ContainerAwareInterface`
- use `ContainerAwareTrait` (for `$container` property and `setContainer` method)
- type-hint `ContainerInterface $container` in command contructor, call `parent::__construct` and `setContainer($container)`

-

```
// ...
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareTrait;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class UploadFromUnreadEmailsCommand extends Command implements ContainerAwareInterface
{
    use ContainerAwareTrait;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setContainer($container);
    }

    // ...

}
```

Also documentation that you links has example with getClient function. Just edit it with some changes:

```
private function getClient()
{
    $projectDir = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.project_dir');
    $credentialsFilePath = sprintf('%s/config/gmail/credentials.json', $projectDir);
    $tokenFilePath = sprintf('%s/config/gmail/token.json', $projectDir);

    // ...
}
```

and in `execute` method:

```
$client = $this->getClient();
$gmail = new \Google_Service_Gmail($client);
```

Execute command and follow instructions (generate token).

Full command class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Style\SymfonyStyle;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareTrait;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class UploadFromUnreadEmailsCommand extends Command implements ContainerAwareInterface
{

    use ContainerAwareTrait;

    protected static $defaultName = 'app:upload-from-unread-emails';

    /**
    * UploadFromUnreadEmailsCommand constructor.
    * @param $container
    */
    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setContainer($container);
    }

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setDescription('Add a short description for your command')
        ;
    }

    private function getClient()
    {
        $projectDir = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.project_dir');
        $credentialsFilePath = sprintf('%s/config/gmail/credentials.json', $projectDir);
        $tokenFilePath = sprintf('%s/config/gmail/token.json', $projectDir);

        $client = new \Google_Client();
        $client->setApplicationName('Gmail API PHP Quickstart');
        $client->setScopes(\Google_Service_Gmail::GMAIL_READONLY);
        $client->setAuthConfig($credentialsFilePath);
        $client->setAccessType('offline');
        $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

        // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
        if (file_exists($tokenFilePath)) {
            $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenFilePath), true);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
        }

        // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
        if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
            // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
            if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
                $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
            } else {
                // Request authorization from the user.
                $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
                printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
                print 'Enter verification code: ';
                $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

                // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
                $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
                $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

                // Check to see if there was an error.
                if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                    throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
                }
            }
            // Save the token to a file.
            if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenFilePath))) {
                mkdir(dirname($tokenFilePath), 0700, true);
            }
            file_put_contents($tokenFilePath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
        }
        return $client;
    }


    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $io = new SymfonyStyle($input, $output);

        $client = $this->getClient();

        $gmail = new \Google_Service_Gmail($client);
        $list = $gmail->users_messages->listUsersMessages('me', ['maxResults' => 10]);

        while ($list->getMessages() != null) {
            foreach ($list->getMessages() as $mlist) {

                $message_id = $mlist->id;
                $io->text($message_id);

            }

            if ($list->getNextPageToken() != null) {
                $pageToken = $list->getNextPageToken();
                $list = $gmail->users_messages->listUsersMessages('me', ['pageToken' => $pageToken, 'maxResults' => 1000]);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        $io->success('Success');
    }
}
```

Also I think better solution is move `getClient` function to a service, where get container parameter, init `\Google_Service_Gmail` and type-hint GmailService in command constructor:

```
# /src/Command/UploadFromUnreadEmailsCommand.php
private $gmailService;
public function __construct(GmailService $gmailService)
{
    $this->gmailService = $gmailService;
}
```